# Is it possible to bulk delete EBS snapshots from the command-line in Windows?

Tags: command-line, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to delete all EBS snapshots except the X newest ones on a Windows AWS instance via the EC2 command-line API tools. I've found the following for Linux, is it possible to do the same in Windows?

> ec2-describe-snapshots | sort -r -k 5 | sed 1,6d | awk '{print
>   "Deleting snapshot: " $2}; system("ec2-delete-snapshot " $2)'

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

Just realized that you apparently want to delete *all* EBS snapshots indeed - in case, the script can be adjusted to this as well via boto's `get_all_snapshots()` method, which, well, gets *all EBS Snapshots associated with the current credentials*.

You'll need to replace the volume oriented code accordingly, e.g. replace

```py
snapshots = volume.snapshots()
```

with

```py
snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots()
```

---

#### Initial Answer

While certainly possible via a combination of the [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) and a respective PowerShell script as well, I personally prefer the excellent [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) to interact with AWS in a platform agnostic way (i.e. the scripts work on Linux, MacOS, Windows) - *Boto is a Python package that provides interfaces to Amazon Web Services*.

I've just been about to assemble something in this regard, but Vaibhav Puranik has it readily available, see [Manage EBS snapshots with a python script](http://aws-musings.com/manage-ebs-snapshots-with-a-python-script/) - his script *creates a new [ebs snapshot](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) and deletes all the previous snapshots except a few newest snapshots*.

So while it offers more functionality than requested, the script is simple enough to be adjusted to your needs, e.g. remove the following two lines to get rid of snapshot creation, if so desired:

```py
if volume.create_snapshot(description):
    print 'Snapshot created with description: ' + description
```

**Disclaimer**: I have neither thoroughly reviewed nor tested the script myself!

Accordingly, given the script deletes data for good, you should review and test it yourself before using it in production.

Good luck!